# Bit strings of even length that start with 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have to give the recursive definition of the set of bit strings of even length that start with 1

We were shown an example that showed the set of all bit strings with no more than a single 1 can be defined as:

Intitial Condition: $(\gamma, 1 \in S)$ 
  Recursion: If $w\in$ S, then $0w \in$ S and $w0 \in$ S.

Do I apply the same method for the question posed above?

Comment: You can -- but the recursion has to preserve the even length, i.e. given $w$ you would need to add some words of the form $\cdot\cdot w$, where each $\cdot$ is a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use the same idea, but of course you have to adapt the definition so you only get exactly those bit strings that are of even length and start with 1. Given these requirements, the initial condition becomes
$$10, 11 \in S.$$
For the recursive step, you have to make sure that you always append an even number of bits at the end of string. In this case, there are four substrings you can append to the string while still keeping the length of the string even.
$$\text{If } w \in S, \text{ then } w10 \in S, w11 \in S, w00 \in S, w01 \in S.$$

Comment: @Jkoz No, because since we know that $10 \in S$, we could then make $11010 \in S$ which has odd length. Hint: If $x \in S$, then we certainly also want $x10 \in S$, but what else do we need?

Comment: @Jkoz I have updated the answer with a full solution.

Comment: If i did that, I can see how the string stays even but how is the string always going to start with one when we flip the bits? Pardon me if i am missing something so easy but I am just trying to understand.

Comment: @Jkoz Do we agree that "starting with one" means that the left-most digit is $1$?

Comment: To me that is what it means so, yes

Comment: @Jkoz Then $10, 11 \in S$, and we know that both of these start with one. Now, by induction hypothesis, $w$ starts with one, so also $w10,w11,w00,$ and $w01$ start with one, since we added $w$ to the left-hand side.

Comment: Ok so that would make $(10)10$, $(10)11$, $(10)00$, $(10)01$,  and so on. This is a crude way for me to understand it but thanks

Comment: @Jkoz Yes, exactly.